# Mysql select max with threshold

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3 tables as part of a car booking system:

```
CREATE TABLE `b_booking` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `b_car_id` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `uc_user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `booking_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `delivery_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `delivery_location` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_b_booking_b_car` (`b_car_id`),
    INDEX `FK_b_booking_uc_users` (`uc_user_id`),
    INDEX `FK_b_booking_b_location` (`delivery_location`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_b_booking_b_location` FOREIGN KEY (`delivery_location`) REFERENCES `b_location` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_b_booking_b_car` FOREIGN KEY (`b_car_id`) REFERENCES `b_car` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_b_booking_uc_users` FOREIGN KEY (`uc_user_id`) REFERENCES `uc_users` (`id`)

CREATE TABLE `b_car` (
    `id` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `b_carmodel_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `day_cost` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `location` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `model_year` SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_b_car_b_carmodel` (`b_carmodel_id`),
    INDEX `FK_b_car_b_location` (`location`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_b_car_b_location` FOREIGN KEY (`location`) REFERENCES `b_location` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_b_car_b_carmodel` FOREIGN KEY (`b_carmodel_id`) REFERENCES `b_carmodel` (`id`)

CREATE TABLE `b_location` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `adress` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `b_postal_zip` SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_b_location_b_postal` (`b_postal_zip`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_b_location_b_postal` FOREIGN KEY (`b_postal_zip`) REFERENCES `b_postal` (`zip`)
```

A given car (b_car) will have an int representing av location where a car can be picked up or delivered. However, this location will change, due to the fact that a customer can pick up the car on one location, and deliver at another. When a customer registers a booking (b_booking), he/she also register at what location the car will be delivered (delivery_location).

I'm however having a lot of problems with what seems to me shouldn't be that hard to do: Lets say a car is at location 1 at the beginning of the month. Then, customer X register a booking for 15-20. and registers a delivery at location 2. Then customer Y wishes to book the same car. So I need a query which takes into account the date and location.

```
SELECT c.id, c.location, b.delivery_location, MAX(b.delivery_date) FROM b_car c
LEFT JOIN b_booking b ON b.b_car_id = c.id
WHERE b.delivery_date < '2012-11-28' OR b.delivery_date IS NULL 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

I have tried something similar to this. I will pick all cars which has no bookings with the left join, and it will also pick the last booking (the last booking related to given date). The problem is, of course, that the where condition also excludes any booking with a date higher than the provided date. Also, with this solution I'm forced to get both the location (from b_car) and the delivery location (from b_booking), and perhaps evaluate null on the delivery_location with php or something.. which really doesnt seem optimal.

Any good solutions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the nature of your problem, can you only have one delivery booking for the car at a time? Then why don't you have a start and an end for the booking(so someone looking for a car that crosses over those dates can be ignored. `AND ( bookingStart < 'END_DATE_STRING' OR bookingEnd > 'START_DATE_STRING' ) ` )?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is. I think your question is to find out which cars are available based on the planning in the booking system on a given day. In that case the only info you need is the ids from the cars and the location and according to the booking system.

BTW I would suggest to add time to your table, because you may want to rent out a car the same day. If customer A returns the car before 12:00 you can easily rent out the same car at 13:00 to customer B.

```
SELECT c.id, b.delivery_location, b.delivery_date FROM b_car AS c
LEFT JOIN b_booking AS b ON b.id = c.id
WHERE b.delivery_date = '2012-11-28' and b.delivery_location = 1;
```

I simplified you query, because I think this will give you the information you need. If a customer wants to rent a car you need to know if the car is available in the planning at the specified location.

If you want to know the availability between to dates use `WHERE b.delivery_date between [start date] AND [end date]`.

I suspect that the type of car is important for the customer, so perhaps it is better to look for a specific car type available at the location of choice.

Furthermore, I would suggest checking if the car is actual at the desired location at the delivery time.